# Unable to resolve service for type for DbContext generated from Scaffold-DbContext and Scaffolded Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I am attempting to use a database first approach and razor pages scaffolding.

Step 1. In package manage console I run

```
Scaffold-DbContext 'MyConnectionStringInfo' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force
```

This generates models for each table as expected, and LoanCalculatorDBContext.cs.

Step 2. I create a folder inside the Pages folder called "LoanEstimateRequests"

Step 3. I right click on the folder and add new scaffolded item "Scaffolded Razor Pages using Entity Framework (CRUD)".

- Model class: LoanEstimateRequest
- Data context class: LoanCalculatorDBContext (the one created in step 1)

Step 4. I then run the application, and navigate to /loanestimaterequests, which results in the following error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'LoanCalculator.Models.LoanCalculatorDBContext' while attempting to
> activate 'LoanCalculator.Pages.LoanEstimateRequests.IndexModel'.

**How can I fix this error? Or should I use a different approach?**

LoanCalculatorDBContext.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;

#nullable disable

namespace LoanCalculator.Models
{
    public partial class LoanCalculatorDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public LoanCalculatorDBContext()
        {
        }

        public LoanCalculatorDBContext(DbContextOptions<LoanCalculatorDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<CreditScore> CreditScores { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LoanEstimateRequest> LoanEstimateRequests { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LoanOfficer> LoanOfficers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LoanType> LoanTypes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PurchaseOrRefinance> PurchaseOrRefinances { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<State> States { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("MyConnectionInfo");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CreditScore>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("CreditScore");

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(25);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<LoanEstimateRequest>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("LoanEstimateRequest");

                entity.Property(e => e.AddressLine1)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsFixedLength(true);

                entity.Property(e => e.AddressLine2)
                    .HasMaxLength(100)
                    .IsFixedLength(true);

                entity.Property(e => e.City)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsFixedLength(true);

                entity.Property(e => e.Email)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(100);

                entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.Zip)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(5)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .HasColumnName("ZIP")
                    .IsFixedLength(true);

                entity.HasOne(d => d.CreditScoreNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.LoanEstimateRequests)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.CreditScore)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_LoanEstimateRequest_CreditScore");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.LoanOfficerNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.LoanEstimateRequests)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.LoanOfficer)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_LoanEstimateRequest_LoanOfficer");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.LoanTypeNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.LoanEstimateRequests)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.LoanType)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_LoanEstimateRequest_LoanType");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.PurchaseOrRefinanceNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.LoanEstimateRequests)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PurchaseOrRefinance)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_LoanEstimateRequest_PurchaseOrRefinance");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.StateNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.LoanEstimateRequests)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.State)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_LoanEstimateRequest_State");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<LoanOfficer>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("LoanOfficer");

                entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);

                entity.Property(e => e.Nmlsnumber)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .HasColumnName("NMLSNumber");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<LoanType>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("LoanType");

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<PurchaseOrRefinance>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("PurchaseOrRefinance");

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<State>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("State");

                entity.Property(e => e.Abbreviation)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(2)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .IsFixedLength(true);

                entity.Property(e => e.DisplayName)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false)
                    .IsFixedLength(true);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LoanCalculator.Models;

namespace LoanCalculator.Pages.LoanEstimateRequests
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly LoanCalculator.Models.LoanCalculatorDBContext _context;

        public IndexModel(LoanCalculator.Models.LoanCalculatorDBContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IList<LoanEstimateRequest> LoanEstimateRequest { get;set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            LoanEstimateRequest = await _context.LoanEstimateRequests
                .Include(l => l.CreditScoreNavigation)
                .Include(l => l.LoanOfficerNavigation)
                .Include(l => l.LoanTypeNavigation)
                .Include(l => l.PurchaseOrRefinanceNavigation)
                .Include(l => l.StateNavigation).ToListAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using LoanCalculator.Data;

namespace LoanCalculator
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
//This was added in another iteration when I had set the Scaffolding Entity Framework CRUD operation to create a new DBContext
            services.AddDbContext<LoanCalculatorContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoanCalculatorContext")));

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls show your startup file.

Comment: Added Startup.cs

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your controller class. How do you start your application.
If it is MVC application, it's a good idea to have Index view and HomeController with Index action
Your configservices should be like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
              
              services.AddDbContext<LoanCalculatorContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoanCalculatorContext")));
  }
```

And replace your UserEndpoints with this code

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
```

Replace protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) method of your LoanCalculatorDBContext with this code

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, can you clarify please? In which file would I place that code snippet, and what goes inside?

Comment: I followed your instructions and get the following error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'LoanCalculator.Models.LoanCalculatorDBContext' while attempting to activate 'LoanCalculator.Pages.LoanEstimateRequests.IndexModel'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired). Is it intentional that there was nothing inside the if? This appears to be the same error I originally got.

Comment: I don't see your controller class.  How do you start your application. You should have Index view and  HomeController with Index action

Comment: It's a razor page app not mvc.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how it can work at all if you don't use mvc.And you tag your question asp.net-core. You can use pazor pages or even webforms with  mvc. You have to change your code to using mvc as I showed in my answer. I don't see any sense to put anything in one page. You are just looking for a trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `DB First`, the dbcontext configuration is set in the `OnConfiguring`  method.

But in .NET Core applications, configuration is more likely to be placed in the Startup class via the ServiceCollection's AddDbContext extension method:

```
services.AddDbContext<LoanCalculatorContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("LoanCalculatorContext")));
```

Like you have done above, also, you need store connection string in appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "LoanCalculatorContext": "MyConnectionInfo"
  }
}
```

`MyConnectionInfo` is the same as that in your LoanCalculatorDBContext `OnConfiguring` method.